# In Django {{user.username}} and {{request.user.username}} return the wrong username in template

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to programming in general and am working on a Django Web-App. I am using a `ChangeUserData` form to update a user's account data (I am using the standard `django.contrib.auth` User model). When a user's attempt to change their username fails because the new username is already in use, the template is displayed again, alongside the relevant error message.

However, the "username" input in the form displays the "new" username, i.e. the one that was rejected for already being in use. I am surprised/confused by this, since in the template I am using `{{ request.user.get_username }}` to fill in this input. **Shouldn't this insert the current user's actual - unchanged - username?**

I have also tried `{{ user.username }}` and `{{ user.get_username }}` but they yield the same result.

Below are excerpts from the relevant files:

**views.py**

```
def MyAccount(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ChangeUserData(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)        
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/myAccount.html', { 'form' : form })
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/myAccount.html')
```

**myAccount.html**

```
 <input type="text" class="inputLocked" name="username" required autocapitalize="none" value="{{user.get_username}}" id="id_username" readonly>
```

Comment: You are not maintaining the `GET` condition for empty form which will appear to the user, you should maintain it, by sending blank form  in it, and are you not getting current user through `user.get_username`?

Answer (score 0):

You should also send empty `ChangeUserData` to be filled by user in `GET` condition, when data is not from `POST` request.

After, validation failed, you don't need to use `render` to fully render `HttpResponse`, here the best choice is to make use of [`messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages)<sup>[django-doc]</sup> framework, which eventually tell user which validation has been failed. But if you have made `ChangeUserData` form through Form Api, so I assume you don't need to do that, since here you can define `error_messages` inside forms.

To get current username, try using `request.user.username`.

> `Note:` Forms in Django requires `Form` to be the suffix so it must be `ChangeUserDataForm` not <s>`changeUserData`</s>

> `Note:` Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` not `PascalCase`, since that's the way how class based views work, so it would be better if you change it to `my_account` from `MyAccount`.

Try below code:

views.py

```py
def my_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ChangeUserDataForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)        
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form=forms.ChangeUserDataForm() #Here empty form for get request.
        return render(request, 'accounts/myAccount.html',{'form':form})
```

myAccount.html

```html
<input type="text" class="inputLocked" name="username" required autocapitalize="none" value="{{request.user.username}}" id="id_username" readonly>
```